# Help with determining if a function is onto (surjective)

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is to determine if the following function $T(x,y,z) = (y\sin x,z\cos y,xy)$ is onto. So far I have only learned of creating a coefficient matrix and checking if the determinant is $0$ to figure out if the function is onto so I have no idea how to proceed with this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the point $(1,0,0)$.  If $T(x,y,z)=(1,0,0)$ then $xy=0$ so $x=0$ or $y=0$.  But then $y\sin x=0$, a contradiction.  Hence $T$ is not onto.

Note: this has nothing to do with linear algebra, as the function is nonlinear.